# Como usar a marcação de código ( `` backticks)?

Tags: debate, respostas

Onde posso ativar as backticks? Não são simples aspas, onde posso ativá-las no corpo de uma pergunta?

Comment: São acentos graves.

Comment: Alguns chamam o acento grave de *crase*, pelo menos no Brasil. Como está na imagem da resposta, você pode também pressionar as teclas <kbd>CTRL+K</kbd> para acrescentar a marcação ao texto atualmente selecionado (se o mesmo estiver dentro de uma linha).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É isto que queres?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: E quanto ao uso de Markdown?

Comment: Que tem? Não estou a perceber...

Comment: Queria saber um exemplo de como  poderia usá-lo!!

Comment: @PenaPintada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help